# how to rotate before translate

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi, i am new to ros, tf
new i need to build a transformation, the parameter for the rotation and translation has already been known, but i wonder how to rotate the frame before translate it, will sendTransform() consider the order?
Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303687/how-to-rotate-before-translate/) by [lanlan](https://answers.ros.org/users/37449/lanlan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2018-09-18

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll need two transforms instead of one, the first with the rotation and then a child one with the translation, and sendTransform them both.

Instead of parent -> child frame you'll have parent -> intermediate rotated child -> child frame, but any tf lookup can ignore the intermediate frame by looking up from parent to child and they'll see the combined proper rotation-then-translation transform.

Or you could do some matrix math to transform the translation in the rotated frame into the parent frame.

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-09-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lanlan](https://answers.ros.org/users/37449/lanlan/) on 2018-09-18**:
that's exactly what i did finally, thank you very much!